Is it possible to set SSL certificate X509 (X509_gmtime_adj) to negative?
I would like to ask if this is possible.
I kept on having problem with my certificate because i set x509_get_notBefore to 0. I received Certificate Unknown error from time to time my assumption is that the client certificate time does not fit to my settings.
Does the solution setting it to negative possible?
// Set the expiration.

From:
X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notBefore(x509), 0); 
X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notAfter(x509), 604800L); // 1 week

To:
X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notBefore(x509), -86400L); // 1 day
X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notAfter(x509), 604800L); // 1 week

Please explain to me the pros and cons for this solution.
Or do you have other suggestions for this problem?

You need to provide more details.  Certificate validity dates are per RFC 5280, 4.1.2.5.  Validity, with two specific formats: 4.1.2.5.1.  UTCTime and 4.1.2.5.2.  GeneralizedTime.  "Adjusting" validity date/times to hide system time errors is likely not going to work.  Offhand, you'd probably have to replace the entire certificate validation code with custom code.

And SSL/TLS handshakes are prone to failures if system times are off, so you need to fix your system times anyway.  https://www.google.com/search?q=tls+fails+with+time+difference

... and to that end, it is usual for systems that want to perform SSL/TLS handshakes successfully to synchronize their system time to a standard time source.  Some operating systems set up such synchronization by default, so that you might not even recognize that it was happening, but there are systems and contexts where you might not get it automatically. Also, even where it's on by default, it is generally possible to turn off such synchronization.

Certificate validation requires a proper understanding of the current time in the system validating the certificate. The point should not be that every site using certificates works around a few broken clients having the wrong time. Instead these clients must fix the problem at their end. And the problem will be faster noticed and fixed if it breaks many things early.

... my assumption is that the client certificate time does not fit to my settings.

No details in your question suggest that this assumption is even true. Therefore one cannot conclude if your proposed idea would be a successful workaround.
